# How to generate an Outlook ribbon?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to create an Outlook ribbon using a VB VSTO program.

I don't receive any error. I don't receive the ribbon.

My code:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        'Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

Public Class ReadPublishing

Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
            RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btnPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) 
            Handles btnPDF.Click
    Dim desktopFolder, fileName As String
    desktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath
                    (Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    fileName = "You press the black one"
    ' --- insert action  
End Sub

End Class

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        'Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? The ribbon button does not show up? You click on a button but your event handler does not get invoked? The code runs but does not do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Improved formatting for better reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: by doesn't work I mean the new ribbon doesn't appear and I don't receive any error.